# Can I use a SCSI Ultra 320 drive instead of SAS

Tags: hard-drive, sas, scsi

I have a bricked SCSI hard drive that I need to replace. It has a SAS interface
[Model ST373455SS](http://www.seagate.com/ww/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=43554e92987c0110VgnVCM100000f5ee0a0aRCRD&locale=en-US)

Can I replace it with this one [Model ST373455LC](http://www.seagate.com/ww/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=3ae6a3b7b59ad010VgnVCM100000dd04090aRCRD&locale=en-US) that has an Ultra320 interface?

Answer (score 3):

Serial attached scsi (SAS) and Ultra320 are not compatiple. They don't have the same interface according to this [article](http://www.newegg.com/product/CategoryIntelligenceArticle.aspx?articleId=209)

Comment: If you have the drive you might check out what buying a U320 controller card off ebay would cost.  Otherwise, a 73G 15k SAS drive will tend to be quite cheap off ebay (An equivalent model from Fujitsu is the MBA3073rc or MAX3073rc)